# Use HMAC with OData Connected Service

Tags: wpf, oauth, odata, hmac, odata-connected-service

So we want to use a webapi that is build in ASP.net and uses OData as protocol. I did some homework and saw that Microsoft has a very good documenten `OData Connected Service`. The only thing I can't find is that the webapi we want to use has a HMAC for security. I cannot find an example where the `OData Connected Service` is used with HMAC. Could someone explain if and how HMAC is possible with the `OData Connected Service`?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the answer depends on the specific implementation of the HMAC on the server side.

If server receives all the data included in the request along with the **Authorization** header and extracts the values (*APP Id*, *Signature*, *Nonce* and *Request Time stamp*) from the **Authorization** header, then client should:

- Build a string by combining all the data that will be sent, this string contains the following parameters (*APP Id*, *HTTP method*, *request URI*, *request time stamp*, *nonce*, and *Base 64 string representation of the request pay load*).
- The signature will be sent in the **Authorization** header using a custom scheme such as ”amx”. The data in the Authorization header will contain the *APP Id*, *request time stamp*, and *nonce* separated by colon ‘:’. The format for the Authorization header will be like: **[Authorization: amx APPId:Signature:Nonce:Timestamp]**.
- Client send the request as usual along with the generated data in the **Authorization** header (just use [client hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/client/using-hooks) or [httpclient](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/odata/client/using-httpclient)).

Example (after generating client code):

```cs
private string APPId = "65d3a4f0-0239-404c-8394-21b94ff50604";
private string APIKey = "WLUEWeL3so2hdHhHM5ZYnvzsOUBzSGH4+T3EgrQ91KI=";

public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> TestODataHMAC()
{
    // add there your OData Uri
    var container = new DefaultContainer(new Uri("https://services.odata.org/V4/(S(qc322lduoxrqt13nhydbdcvx))/TripPinServiceRW/")); 
    container.Configurations.RequestPipeline.OnMessageCreating = (args) =>
    {
        var request = new HttpWebRequestMessage(args);

        // Get the Request URI
        string requestUri = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower());

        // Calculate UNIX time
        var epochStart = new DateTime(1970, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        var timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow - epochStart;
        var requestTimeStamp = Convert.ToUInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString();

        // Create the random nonce for each request
        var nonce = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        // Creating the raw signature string by combinging
        // APPId, request Http Method, request Uri, request TimeStamp, nonce
        var signatureRawData = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}", APPId, request.Method, requestUri, requestTimeStamp, nonce);

        // Converting the APIKey into byte array
        var secretKeyByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(APIKey);

        // Converting the signatureRawData into byte array
        var signature = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signatureRawData);

        // Generate the hmac signature and set it in the Authorization header
        using (HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(secretKeyByteArray))
        {
            var signatureBytes = hmac.ComputeHash(signature);
            var requestSignatureBase64String = Convert.ToBase64String(signatureBytes);

            //Setting the values in the Authorization header using custom scheme (hmacauth)
            request.SetHeader("Authorization", string.Format("hmacauth {0}:{1}:{2}:{3}", APPId, requestSignatureBase64String, nonce, requestTimeStamp));
        }

        return request;
    };

    // add there your OData method call 
    var nquery = container.People.Where(p => p.Gender == PersonGender.Female).Take(10) as DataServiceQuery<Person>;
    var response = await nquery?.ExecuteAsync();
    return (response as QueryOperationResponse<Person>).Select(p => p.FirstName).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! In this case a MD5 HASH of the content is also requested so how would one HASH the content/body in the `OnMessageCreating` ?

Comment: At the moment, I do not know the right way to do this. Unless to somehow receive the body of the request before the call, and put it into `container.Configurations.RequestPipeline.OnMessageCreating`.

Can you change server logic to avoid request body in the HMAC authorization header?
Then you can use the HMAC without the request body in the client side.